# Set flag value in DB query

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle12c

My query updates a table if a particular ID exists else it inserts a new value.

I want to implement something like -:

```
if(exists){
   update table,
   flag = 0}
else{
   insert into table,
   flag = 1}
return flag;
```

My existing query is

```
BEGIN
merge into FCM_DEVICE_REGISTRATION u 
using dual
on (device_ad_id = 1) 
when matched then 
            update set fcm_notification_id='N',
                       last_update_date = SYSDATE
when not matched then 
insert (device_ad_id,fcm_notification_id) values (1,'Y');
 END;
```

Comment: Are you getting at `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`?

Comment: what is the db engine you are using?

Comment: @LelioFaieta oracle 12g

Comment: @JonStirling : yes, but I need to know if the table was updated or inserted into.

Comment: And why did you tag all the other db engine except this one? :)

Comment: So the merge statement works for you, but you also want to know after running it whether it applied the update or the insert?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: Yes

Comment: @Atmesh Mishra in the insert statement there is not the last_update_date, so this value is null; you can check this to know if there was an update or an insert (or there is a default / trigger on this column?).

Comment: and what do you expect if it updates 10 rows and inserts 5 new rows?
I meant there may be scenarios where it would perform both update/inset.

Comment: @PrashantMishra : No it wont happen. Query works for one row only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running `MERGE` you can use `SQL%ROWCOUNT` to get the number of rows affected. You cannot, however, find out whether an insert or updated was applied or even how many rows were updated and how many inserted. So you must check whether the row in question exists beforehand. And, well, then you know whther to update or insert yourself, so you don't need `MERGE` anymore.

```
DECLARE
  v_count integer;
BEGIN
  select count(*) into v_count 
  from fcm_device_registration
  where device_ad_id = 1;

  if v_count = 0 then
    insert into fcm_device_registration 
      (device_ad_id, fcm_notification_id) values (1, 'Y');
  else
    update fcm_device_registration
    set fcm_notification_id = 'N', last_update_date = sysdate
    where device_ad_id = 1;
  end;
END;
```

The variable `v_count` contains 0 or 1 (as you say that the device_ad_id is unique in the table). It is 1 for update and 0 for insert. Just the opposite of what you want. However, you can easily derive your flag from this: `v_flag := 1 - v_count`.

Comment: So there is no way to do this in one DB call?

Comment: This *is* one DB call. If you mean "one SQL statement", then no, but there are no variables in SQL anyway, so you cannot get a "flag" from insert, update, delete or merge.

Answer (score 1):

```
BEGIN
update  fcm_device_registration 
set fcm_notification_id='N',
last_update_date = SYSDATE
where device_ad_id = 1;
--in case of no update
if sql%rowcount = 0 then
  insert into fcm_device_registration(device_ad_id,fcm_notification_id) values (1,'Y');
  dbms_output.put_line('insert');
else  
  dbms_output.put_line('update');-- in case of record update
end if;
END;
```